# Testcontainers Postgresql mocking does not work

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, mocking, testcontainers

I need to mock the postgresql database, and after some research I decided to go with **Tescontainers-Python**.
After pip installing the Testcontainer i**n Python3.6**, an initial code I found to begin is simple as it can be:

```
from testcontainers.postgres import PostgresContainer

postgres_container = PostgresContainer("postgres:9.5")
postgres_container.start()
sql_url = postgres_container.get_connection_url()
```

Python 3.8 too, under Windows 10 or Ubuntu I am getting always the same error message, am I missing something?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 672, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 387, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1287, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1333, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1282, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1042, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 980, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 43, in connect
    sock.connect(self.unix_socket)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 720, in urlopen
    method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 400, in increment
    raise six.reraise(type(error), error, _stacktrace)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/six.py", line 702, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 672, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked,
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 387, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1287, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1333, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1282, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1042, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 980, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 43, in connect
    sock.connect(self.unix_socket)
urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 205, in _retrieve_server_version
    return self.version(api_version=False)["ApiVersion"]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/docker/api/daemon.py", line 181, in version
    return self._result(self._get(url), json=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/docker/utils/decorators.py", line 46, in inner
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 228, in _get
    return self.get(url, **self._set_request_timeout(kwargs))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 546, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 498, in send
    raise ConnectionError(err, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "***.py", line 4, in <module>
    postgres_container = PostgresContainer("postgres:9.5")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/testcontainers/postgres.py", line 36, in __init__
    super(PostgresContainer, self).__init__(image=image)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/testcontainers/core/generic.py", line 21, in __init__
    super(DbContainer, self).__init__(image)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/testcontainers/core/container.py", line 16, in __init__
    self._docker = DockerClient()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/testcontainers/core/docker_client.py", line 23, in __init__
    self.client = docker.from_env()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/docker/client.py", line 85, in from_env
    timeout=timeout, version=version, **kwargs_from_env(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/docker/client.py", line 40, in __init__
    self.api = APIClient(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 188, in __init__
    self._version = self._retrieve_server_version()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/docker/api/client.py", line 213, in _retrieve_server_version
    'Error while fetching server API version: {0}'.format(e)
docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))
Exception ignored in: <bound method DockerContainer.__del__ of <testcontainers.postgres.PostgresContainer object at 0x7ff612c65390>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/testcontainers/core/container.py", line 73, in __del__
AttributeError: 'PostgresContainer' object has no attribute '_container'
```

Comment: File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/docker/transport/unixconn.py", line 43, in connect
    sock.connect(self.unix_socket)
There seems to be a problem with the connection to the Docker daemon, is it running?

Comment: no Idea, do you know how to check this?

Comment: Do you have Docker installed then?) ("docker run hello-world" in your terminal for finding out).

Testcontainers doesn't run containers idependently, it requires Docker.
https://www.testcontainers.org/supported_docker_environment/
https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/
Are good places to start.

Comment: thanks for the tips Vitaly. At the end we decided not to use testcontainers, since we want to mock the database, not to install a standalone test db in a docker.

Comment: I think you might have misunderstood. It won't be a standalone db. Testcontainers manages the container lifecycle and stops it at the end of a test. It just needs a Docket daemon to run containers on something.

You can use H2 to mock db, what Testcontainers is for is full db mocking. With H2 there might be syntax differences or some issues specific to a real db that cannot be reproduced on H2. With Testcontainers you actually run tests against the real db, which is brought up before the test and shut down afterwards.

Comment: exactly, that running against the real db is not mocking. if you want to learn what mocking is, look at moto. In this sense you  misunderstood what mocking is..